# Unicode Blocks: get alphabet of every language [Java]

Tags: java, unicode, alphabet

I have searched so much now and hope that somebody can help me. I want to get the Unicode Blocks of every language in Java. What I have found so far is:

- Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC; Character.UnicodeBlock.Cyrillic;
- Character.UnicodeBlock.LATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT; ....

But this is not enough. I also want to know, which letters are in the German, French, Russian alphabet. I can only get that they correspond to Latin or Cyrillic, but not language specific alphabets like [this](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/by_type/misc.exemplarCharacters.html).

Comment: I don't think this is possible—the character sets for languages aren't that well defined. For example, "ç" is a legitimate character in English used in "façade." The CJK character block (Chinese, Japanese and Korean) is also pretty well mixed together because there is a lot of overlap.

Comment: Ok, "ç" is maybe a legitimate character in english but I don't think that you learned in you childhood that there are more than A-Z characters in the english alphabet or?

Comment: The alphabet is still just A-Z, but sometimes c might have a tail (ç), e might have an accent (é), etc. If you want to go into more archaic English, then you also get weird forms of letters like "ſ" ([long s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s)). German, French and English all use the same Latin alphabet: A-Z. How do you want to partition that? (btw, the German letter ß is actually just the "long s" I just mentioned followed by a normal s: ſs => ß)

Comment: I don't want to say that these characters (ç)(é) shouldn't be display in english. It's like these language rules you have a rule but every rule also has exeptions. Now it is the same with the english alphabet and in [LocaleData](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j50m1/com/ibm/icu/util/LocaleData.html) you have the standard and auxiliary UnicodeSet, which represents exactly what we are talking about.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. These are just weird edge cases that basically never come up, and it's actually acceptable to write them without the accents. I'm glad I was wrong and you were able to find a suitable answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out ICU class [LocaleData](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j50m1/com/ibm/icu/util/LocaleData.html). It gives access to CLDR elements such as exemplarCharacters, by locale.

Beware that exemplarCharacters is rather vaguely defined (the concept of being a character used in a language is inherently vague, too), and hence the values for it have not been defined on a solid basis, and many choices made there are rather arguably. But the data there is probably still be best basis we have in general.

Also note that Unicode blocks are rather coarse units in this context. For example, the Latin 1 Supplement block contains characters used in many languages, but no language uses all the letters in it.

Comment: if anybody is missing the com.ibm.icu package as me here is a download:[link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j/4.8.1) Just import that to your build path and be happy

Answer (score 2):

> I also want to know, which letters are in the german, french, russian alphabet.

I don't think Unicode supports this.  For example, nothing in Unicode says which Latin-based characters are used in which Western European language.

In fact, I have a feeling that it is not even possible to make that call definitively.  For instance, I recall reading an edition of a 19th century English classic in which the author / publisher spelled the word "role" as "rôle".  It happens quite a lot when languages borrow words from others.

Comment: The Unicode Standard makes many notes on the use of characters in different languages, though it does not even try to describe such things systematically. There *are* attempt at systematic descriptions, especially in the CLDR activity. It is true that the issue is vague, but it is nonetheless important in practice, so people have tried to find “good enough” classifications.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to get alphabets and collation orders of languages is here:
http://developer.mimer.com/charts/index.tml
http://developer.mimer.com/charts/tailorings.htm

Eg. the Finnish alphabet:
http://developer.mimer.com/charts/finnish.htm
http://developer.mimer.com/charts/tailorings.htm#Finnish

German:
http://developer.mimer.com/charts/german.htm
http://developer.mimer.com/charts/tailorings.htm#German